# In the language translator code using tkinter, how to save the output as a pdf?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a language translator app using tkinter using the following code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.ttk import *
from googletrans import LANGUAGES
import translate

root = tk.Tk()

src_text = Text(root, font="arial 10", height=11, wrap=WORD, padx=5, pady=5, width=60)
src_text.place(x=50, y=120)

des_text = Text(root, font="arial 10", height=11, wrap=WORD, padx=5, pady=5, width=60)
des_text.place(x=600, y=120)


class Lang_Translator(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.pack()
        self.label()
    
    src_text = Text(root)
    des_text = Text(root)
    
    def label(self):
        Label(root, text="Language Translator", font="italic 20").pack(side="top")
        Label(root, text="Select Language", font="arial 15").place(x=30, y=60)
        Label(root, text="Select Language", font="arial 15").place(x=600, y=60)


lang = list(LANGUAGES.values())
src_lang = ttk.Combobox(root, values=lang, width=30)
src_lang.place(x=200, y=63)
src_lang.set("english")

des_lang = ttk.Combobox(root, values=lang, width=30)
des_lang.place(x=770, y=63)
des_lang.set("hindi")


def trans():
    translator2 = translate.Translator(to_lang=des_lang.get())
    translated = translator2.translate(src_text.get(0.0, END))
    des_text.insert(0.0, translated)


def clear_all():
    des_text.delete(0.0, END)
    src_text.delete(0.0, END)


button_1 = Button(root, text="Translate", command=trans).place(x=510, y=160)
button_2 = Button(root, text="Clear", command=clear_all).place(x=510, y=220)

app = Lang_Translator(master=root)
app.master.title('Translator')
app.master.geometry('1080x350')
app.mainloop()
```

How do I save the output, the translated language, as a pdf file?

I tried to make a separate function to save pdf using fpdf package.

```
def savepdf():
    pdf = FPDF()
    pdf.add_page()
    pdf.set_font("Arial", size=15)
    pdf.cell(200, 10, txt="Language Translator", ln=1, align='C')
    pdf.cell(10, 200, txt=str(), ln=2, align='L')
    pdf.output("Translated.pdf")
```

and tried to use the `translated` variable from `trans()` function.

```
def trans():
    translator2 = translate.Translator(to_lang=des_lang.get())
    translated = translator2.translate(src_text.get(0.0, END))
    des_text.insert(0.0, translated)
```

But I am stuck on how to do that. So how do you save the output as pdf using this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`translated` is a local variable inside `trans()` and it cannot be accessed elsewhere.  However you can use `des_text.get(1.0, "end-1c")` instead:

```py
def save_pdf():
    pdf = FPDF()
    pdf.add_page()
    pdf.set_font("Arial", size=15)
    pdf.cell(200, 10, txt="Language Translator", ln=1, align="C")
    pdf.cell(10, 200, txt=des_text.get(1.0, "end-1c"), ln=2, align="L")
    pdf.output("translated.pdf")
```